# How do I replace ", ," with ","

Tags: javascript

My string is as follows **"Increase in housing cost,  Create sense of Financial security,  Reduced Travel,  ,Happiness for Family, Financial Security".**
I want to remove the space and extra comma in the string using JavaScript. So the final string should be **"Increase in housing cost,  Create sense of Financial security,  Reduced Travel, Happiness for Family, Financial Security"**
The string is coming from a variable "myString"
I tried using
`myString = myString.replace(", ,",",");` but it does not work.

Comment: `replace(", ,", ", ")` - you missed the space in the second argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match `,` and `,` with whitespace (or none) in between them. This is called regular expression or regexp and it's a language to describe actions that can be done on text (this is my free interpretation).

In this specific instance, this matches comma followed by \s (whitespace) 0 or more times `*` then followed by comma. The `g` at the end means match all not only the first.

```js
var reg = /,\s*,/g
console.log("Increase in housing cost, Create sense of Financial security, Reduced Travel, ,Happiness for Family, Financial Security".replace(reg, ', '))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Can you please explain the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
let myString = "Increase in housing cost, Create sense of Financial security, Reduced Travel, ,Happiness for Family, Financial Security";
myString  = myString.replaceAll(", ,",",")
```